# Actually finding converging value of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have sequence where $x_{1} < x_{2}$ and $x_{n} = \frac{1}{3}x_{n-1} + \frac{2}{3}x_{n-2}$. My question asked to show that it must converge. I did this not too badly, showing $|x_{n+3} - x_{n+2}| = \frac{4}{9}|x_{n+1} - x_{n}|$ so the difference between values is getting contracting smaller, then I can show it is Cauchy-sequence, then I can show it converges.

But I was wondering, if I had some values for $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, i.e. $1$ and $3$, how would I try and find what the actual value the sequence converges to is? I can't really use my above result I don't think, so I am sort of stuck for a method.

Comment: $$x_n = x_1 + (x_2 - x_1) + \dotsc + (x_n - x_{n-1})$$

Comment: @DanielFischer So simple, wow. Should I delete my question?

Comment: You could also solve the recurrence relation using the standard techniques, no cleverness, to obtain $$\frac{1}{5} 3^{-n} (3 \times (-2)^n (y_1 - y_2) + 3^n (2 y_1 + 3 y_2))$$

Comment: @BiXa I think it's worth keeping, personally.

Comment: @DanielFischer The one only thing I'm stuck on with your trick, is that I only proved that $|x_{n+2} - x_{n-1}| = \frac{4}{9}|x_{n}-x_{n-1}|$. I seem to be having trouble making justifying of geometrically factoring each term as result. I don't want to ask you how, but just make sure it is possible?

Comment: Forget about the absolute values. If you calculate $x_n - x_{n-1}$ using the recurrence, what do you get?

Comment: Ohhh I see. Thanks for your tips @DanielFischer

Answer (score 0):

At first, I was a bit stuck on this. Then I realised it's actually quite easy! Just solve the difference equation! I guess you've come across these, since you solved showing that it converges in a reasonably advanced way -- that is, beyond A-Level (or whatever the US equivalent is). If you haven't, think about how you would solve it if instead it were a related differential equation (with derivative "powers" *relating* to the subscripts).

Comment: Ok, so as you've pointed out, in this case it's not actually difficult. Try changing the coefficients slightly so that that trick doesn't work, and then solve it using a more general way. (Or, you know, don't, if you don't want to. =P - Your life, not mine!)